# Any way to prevent Firefox scaling on second monitor?

Tags: firefox, multiple-monitors, scaling

So, the background on this issue. I had two monitors. A 1080p Samsung monitor, and a 1440x900 Philips TV. On my old Radeon HD 5770, I connected the monitor via HDMI and the TV via VGA and set both to their native resolution and everything worked fine.

I switched to a 290x which no longer had any analog outputs, so now I have the monitor connected via HDMI and the TV connected via a DVI->HDMI converter. This only allows me to set the 1440x900 TV to one of four resolutions: 1920x1080, 1600x900, 1280x720 or 1024x768. So I set it to 1080p and let either my graphics card or the TV itself downscale it. I also turned off all scaling options in the windows control panel.

And this works, for everything except Firefox, which inexplicably doubles everything in size when the centre of the window is on the second monitor.

For illustration, here's a screenshot.

[image: Firefox Craziness]

The left window is Firefox, on the primary monitor at a reasonable size. The rightmost window is Chrome, on the secondary monitor, also at a reasonable size. The middle window is Firefox, on the secondary monitor and doing some weird scaling of its own.

IS there any way to disable or fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some options to try out in the about:config page of Firefox,
see e.g. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/959621

More info:
https://www.google.se/?gfe_rd=cr&safe=off#q=firefox+about+config+scaling+multiple+displays&safe=off

Comment: This option affects scaling on both monitors, not the secondary monitor only scaling I'm seeing.

Comment: There seems to be an option to disable system DPI-lookup, how about that?

Comment: Is that layout.css.dpi? That didn't help either. If you notice, it's the entire window that's scaled, not just CSS. The UI is scaled, the embedded flash video is scaled, etc.

Comment: From that it appears to me that the OS reports the scaling, Firefox picks it up and uses it - I have not seen this before *out of clues*. I'll leave this as is, somebody else might get ideas out of it.